# Word to specify short in the longitudinal sense only

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a text about rectangular plates (skirts) that are mounted to semi-trailers, as shown in the image below:

[image]

[Source](https://www.truck-drivers-money-saving-tips.com/side-skirts.html)

In the text, we want to emphasize that our products are shorter (in the longitudinal sense) than those used before. At the moment we describe them as 'shorter', but we got feedback from our proofreaders that they associated 'shorter' with the vertical length (height).
I thought about 'shorter length' skirts, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative. I repeat this feature several times, so it would be good to have some alternatives to avoid word repetition.

**Is there a way to describe 'shorter in the longitudinal sense' in a brief way?**

Comment: You may need a diagram—a graphic or picture of what you’re doing. Shorter length sounds right to me, though.  Length, height, width,

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is exactly the issue. However, there are words that are tied to a certain direction, like for example 'tall', so I'm hoping there is something similar for other directions too.

Comment: _Slim_: (of a thing) small in width and typically long and narrow in shape. — [Oxford Languages via Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev1&sxsrf=ALeKk02UW5cXsgWnEr0Kyaht4fPixaZziA%3A1608550589006&ei=vIjgX5b5PPDjz7sP6omamAo&q=slim+meaning&oq=slim+meaning&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyCQgjECcQRhD5ATIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgQIABBDMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjoECAAQRzoHCCMQsQIQJzoICAAQBxAKEB5Q2fQCWNP5AmC7-wJoAHABeACAAbsBiAH-A5IBAzAuM5gBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp); comparative: "slimmer".

Comment: I say ignore those proofreaders: what you report they say is nonsense. (Can a *shorter* race than the 400 meters be run only among human flies?)

Comment: The question is desperately in need of the sentence in which the term is used and a full description of the article. It could well be that, given the shape of the article, "shorter" does not help.

Comment: @KannE I added an image to show what objects I am talking about.

Comment: @BrianDonovan, I think I should not ignore the comments of the proofreaders. Iif they are confused, it's likely future readers will also be. I think the 400-meter race is not a good example, as here both options (i.e. change in height and change in length) are equally likely.

Comment: I'm tempted to recommend words like "compact" (as opposed to "extended"). "Our line of compact side skirts..." may well be the best you can possibly do using only one word.

Answer (score 1):

[**Narrow** is an alternative that is associated with width rather than height. ] - was original answer before the OP changed their question to be more specific.

---

EDIT AFTER UPDATE TO QUESTION: Another option that implies reduction in length of the largest dimension is **truncate**

Comment: narrower, less wide, slimmer (as a more colloquial version) are all good options indeed

Comment: I'm not convinced about this answer myself. The "width" of the skirt is an ill-defined term for anyone who understands that the skirt is a panel that runs longitudinally and not laterally, and a person may easily resort to thinking that the "width" relates to the height (the very problem the OP starts with) or even the thickness of the skirt.

Comment: @Steve indeed, I answered the question when it was being asked in general terms and not with a specific example so I am inclined to agree with you now that we can see to what the OP is referring.

Comment: Narrow refers to the smallest dimension, rather than to any particular direction. For instance the narrowness of a tunnel would be the distance across from left to right as you look along the tunnel; for a tube, the narrowness is the diameter (regardless of orientation); although for a tower, narrowness is the distance across (width not height).

Comment: @StuartF kindly read my above comment. The OP changed their question after my initial answer.